# How can I restart an app game from the beginning

Tags: ipad, games, restart

I would like to restart two games, bubble safari and bubbleseason, from the beginning. When I delete the app and reinstall it from the App Store all my old data is on there and I start from the same level I left it at, I want to start all over from scratch.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible to start over. Many games will save your profile in a separate folder. Please provide more information, like what game ? The issue is with that game is saving your profile that stays even after reinstall. So to find it please tell us what game it is or find your game profile on your computer

Comment: I did this once (by mistake) on my iPhone by deleting an app and having to re-download it.  But maybe whether this works depends on the app...

Comment: It's on my iPad 2 and the games are bubble safari and bubbleseason

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the game from iOS devices usually removes the game stored data, unless, those data are stored in iCloud. Here are the steps to delete saved games data in iCloud.

1. **Make sure you’ve deleted the games you want to reset**. Some of those games will push the local saved data to iCloud even if you’ve deleted the data in iCloud.
2. Access those saved games data in `Setting > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage`.
3. Select `Show All` to view all the saved data. You’ll see non-games app in this location too because it shows all your iCloud storage.
4. Tap on the games you want to reset.
5. Tap `Edit` at the top right.
6. Tap `Delete All` to delete the saved games data.

Comment: this is the correct answer, you need to combine it with reinstall of the app however!

Answer (score -4):

You might have to delete all the saved game data. It might take a while, but the most thorough approach is to search the entire computer if you don't know where this data coudl be saved. Therefore open a terminal and type

```
sudo find / -name "yourgame" -print
```

And delete all the files that are showing up if you think that these might relate to the saved game status.

EDIT: I didn't see that you were looking for a solution on iOS. In this case you should be able to delete the app with it's associated data in iTunes on your Mac. It should work if you delete the app from your iTunes library

[image]

Comment: Deleting the app from iTunes only does just that - deletes the app file. The user's data for that app is stored in the iOS backup for that device, separately. Deleting the app from iTunes just means it will have to be re-downloaded the next time the device is synced.